# Java Web App in Eclipse with Spring Framework not recognizing edits to controller

Tags: eclipse, spring, jsp, tomcat

I was given an existing dashboard at work and am new to the whole Java Servlets with Spring Framework deal.

So the pages that are there work, and the flow is that there is the @RequestMapping annotation for the method inside the controller. For Example

```
@RequestMapping("/index.do")
public ModelAndView index() throws Exception {
    LoginDO oLoginDO = new LoginDO();       
    return new ModelAndView("index","oLoginDO",oLoginDO);
}
```

The servlet.xml file maps the views to jsp files, and it's all working.

But my issue is, when I edit the controller.java file and create another method returning a new view, which is for a new page to the webpage, the change isn't being recognized by the servlet. It says "No matching handler method found for servlet request."

Now here's the thing, I believe this is happening because somehow the Spring Framework isn't being "updated" (don't know if this is the right term) when the edits are made in controller.java. I deployed my source code from a WAR file in Eclipse, then run it on a Tomcat server. Here's the deal, my mentor's code is working fine along with the edits, but I believe that he created a Tomcat project, and the project directories are different, and the edits are updated onto the website immediately after a save.

Note that when I change the JSPs to the existing pages, the updates are recognized immediately, it's only when I create a new JSP and a new @RequestMapping annotation along with a new method, it's not working. I even tried print statements within the controller.java and nothings showing.

So I guess this is an Eclipse question and deployment question more than anything, but any help would be great! Not too sure what to do to fix this. I've even tried restarting the server, to no success though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

New @RequestMapping methods require the context to be reloaded (updated) to make them be available. When STS (Eclipse) detects changes on a spring bean it reloads the context automatically. If you are having problems with this try redeploying the project or restarting Tomcat.

Also, I wonder if you are you putting that new @RequestMapping method in a new Controller or in an existing one. If it's a new controller, have you added that Controller to the Spring Web Context (e.g. @Controller + component-scan or just adding the bean to de config file).

Comment: Mmm, it's for sure an existing controller. I have tried to restart Tomcat. However, I think my problem may be that the project is a Java Web Project, as I imported the WAR file and that's what Eclipse automatically did for me. Rather, my coworkers have the project as a Tomcat project, and they can do things like reload the context by choosing from a Tomcat dropdown from the plugin.